# Controlling Carousel Slider from Stream (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I have data coming from a stream mainly a queue and current `mediaItem` of the queue. So the `mediaItem` is always changing.
I got the index using

> index = queue.indexOf(mediaItem);

now I want to set the carousel's current page to my index, I added the index on the `initialPage` of the Carousel but it works only once when the index changes it doesn't change the current page.

My Stream looks like this

```
//this stream is initialized inside initState()
stream = Rx.combineLatest3<List<MediaItem>, MediaItem, PlaybackState, ScreenState>(
  AudioService.queueStream,
  AudioService.currentMediaItemStream,
  AudioService.playbackStateStream,
      (queue, mediaItem, playbackState) => ScreenState(queue, mediaItem, playbackState)
);


Scaffold(
  body: new Center(
    child: StreamBuilder<ScreenState>(
      stream: stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        final screenState = snapshot.data;
        final queue = screenState?.queue;
        final mediaItem = screenState?.mediaItem;
        final state = screenState?.playbackState;
        final basicState = state?.basicState ?? BasicPlaybackState.none;
        int index = queue?.indexWhere((MediaItem mediaItemX){return (mediaItem?.id == mediaItemX.id);});
        return (queue!=null&& mediaItem!=null && basicState != null && index != null) 
          ? mainView(queue, mediaItem, basicState, state, index)
          : Container(
            child: Center(
              child: SpinKitWave(
                color: Colors.white70,
              ),
            ),
          );
      },
    ),
  ),
),
```

**Main view**

```
Widget mainView(List<MediaItem> queue, MediaItem mediaItemX, BasicPlaybackState basicState, PlaybackState state, int index){
  return CarouselSlider.builder(
    itemCount: queue.length,
    initialPage: queue.indexOf(mediaItemX),//only works first time
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemIndex) {
      Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,0,0),
              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                height: ScreenUtil().setWidth(1200),
                width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(1200),
                imageUrl: queue[itemIndex].artUri,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                placeholder: (context, url) => new SpinKitWave(color: Colors.white30, size: 30.0,),
                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Image.asset(
                  'images/addplaylist.png',
                  color: Colors.white30,
                ),
              ),
            )
          )
        ],
      ),
    }
  );
}
```

The issue is when `mediaItem` changes from another place, the carousel is needed to change its index based on the stream change of data, In other words, a functionality almost same as currentPage inside Carousel so that every time index changes then the `currentPage` is set to the new data from the stream or to control the Carousel from the stream.
A solution or a hint with an example is highly appreciated.

Additional Information: I am using [carousel_slider: ^1.4.1](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider)

Comment: Consider passing a `pageController` to your `CarousselSlider`, and make your stream modify that controller

Comment: @RémiRousselet Can you give an example of how to do that?  because the carousel still has to be inside the StreamBuilder and to control is using pageController the carousel must already be built.

Comment: As stated [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html), because **StreamBuilder is a Widget that builds itself based on the latest snapshot of interaction with a Stream**, it should have changed the page when the index changes directly from the stream rebuilding the carouselSlider including its initialPage data with the new index value.

Comment: I am not sure if it's related to [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20416), I have tried the fix in there, seems not working.

Comment: Changing `initialPage` will not change the current page. The `initialPage` is used only for the very first rendering and is ignored afterward

Comment: Even if the carousel is rebuilt is the initial page ignored?

Comment: Yes. You need a `PageController`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207773/discussion-between-henok-and-remi-rousselet).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

initialPage works properly with empty containers (see code below), seems to me that is missing some `key` maybe in cached image network or your container, try put a `UniqueKey()` to ensure that widget tree will detect the change when new snapshot comes...

Example working with `StreamBuilder` and slider:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(body: MyHomePage()),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final StreamController sc = StreamController();
  final rng = Random();

  final containers = [
    Container(color: Colors.pink),
    Container(color: Colors.black),
    Container(color: Colors.yellow),
    Container(color: Colors.brown),
  ];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Timer.periodic(
      Duration(seconds: 5),
      (t) {
        sc.add(rng.nextInt(containers.length));
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: sc.stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData == false) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        return Container(
          child: mainView(containers, containers[snapshot.data]),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget mainView(
    List<Container> queue,
    Container mediaItemX,
  ) {
    return CarouselSlider.builder(
      itemCount: queue.length,
      initialPage: queue.indexOf(mediaItemX), //only works first time
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemIndex) {
        print('changed');
        
        return mediaItemX;
      },
    );
  }
}
```